# React Big Calendar - Custom prop in a custom view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-big-calendar

I have a year custom view in react-big-calendar lib.

```
<Calendar
  localizer={localizer}
  events={events || []}
  startAccessor="start"
  endAccessor="end"
  defaultView="year"
  views={{
    year: YearView
  }}
  components={{
    toolbar: props => (<Toolbar {...props} />)
  }}
/>
```

I need to pass another prop in the YearView, I tried to pass like this

```
<Calendar
  localizer={localizer}
  events={events || []}
  startAccessor="start"
  endAccessor="end"
  defaultView="year"
  views={{
    year: props => (
      <YearView
        {...props}
        onCreateOrEdit={onCreateOrEdit}
      />
    )
  }}
  components={{
    toolbar: props => (<Toolbar {...props} />)
  }}
/>
```

but does't works, pops up the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".
Another solution is using React Context, but in my case this isn't a option, because I'm using monorepo and the components is in another app folder.

The YearView component

```
    export const YearView = React.memo(({
      events, 
      onCreateOrEdit, 
      range, 
      date, 
      action, 
      localizer, 
      ...props 
    }) => {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = React.useState(false)
    const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = React.useState('')
    const [isEventosDoDia, setIsEventosDoDia] = 
      React.useState(false)
    const [dialogEventsArray, setDialogEventsArray] = 
      React.useState(events);
    const [months, setMonths] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
     const monthsArray = []
     const firstMonth = dates.startOf(date, 'year')
     
     for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       monthsArray.push(
        <Calendar
          key={i + 1}
          date={dates.add(firstMonth, i, 'month')}
          eventosDoMes={
            events.filter(
              meses => meses.mes === getMonthByNumber(i)
          )}
          modalTitle={modalTitle}
          setModalTitle={(title) => setModalTitle(title)}
          listaDeEvento={dialogEventsArray}
          setListaDeEvento={(
            eventos) => setDialogEventsArray(eventos
          )}
          isEventosDoDia={isEventosDoDia}
          setIsEventosDoDia={(
            eventosDia) => setIsEventosDoDia(eventosDia
          )}
          modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
          setModalIsOpen={(isOpen) => setModalIsOpen(isOpen)}
        />
      )
    }

     setMonths(monthsArray)
    }, [date, isEventosDoDia, modalIsOpen, modalTitle])

    return (
      <YearContainer {...props}>
        <EventsDialog
          isOpen={modalIsOpen}
          title={modalTitle}
          eventsList={dialogEventsArray}
          isEventosDoDia={isEventosDoDia}
          setModalIsOpen={(isOpen) => setModalIsOpen(isOpen)}
       />
           
       {months.map((month) => month)}
      </YearContainer>
    )
    })

    YearView.navigate = (date, action) => {
      switch (action) {
       case navigate.PREVIOUS:
        return dates.add(date, -1, 'year')

       case navigate.NEXT:
        return dates.add(date, 1, 'year')

       default:
        return date
     }
    }

    YearView.title = (date, { localizer }) => 
      localizer.format(date, 'YYYY')
```

And the console.log for the props in the YearVew file.

```
"props": {
    "startAccessor": "start",
    "endAccessor": "end",
    "views": {
        "year": {
            "compare": null
        }
    },
    "popup": false,
    "step": 30,
    "drilldownView": "day",
    "titleAccessor": "title",
    "tooltipAccessor": "title",
    "allDayAccessor": "allDay",
    "resourceAccessor": "resourceId",
    "resourceIdAccessor": "id",
    "resourceTitleAccessor": "title",
    "longPressThreshold": 250,
    "dayLayoutAlgorithm": "overlap",
    "backgroundEvents": [],
    "length": 30,
    "getters": {},
    "components": {},
    "accessors": {},
    "doShowMoreDrillDown": true
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the YearView component and give us the result of console.log({props}) in YearView ?

Comment: Yes, of course! I edited the post with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

First, I noticed you memoized your YearView component. This may be causing issues with creating and using the static `title` method.

I also noticed you added the prop directly to the component in the `views` definition, rather than as a prop of `Calendar` itself.

```js
<Calendar
  localizer={localizer}
  events={events || []}
  startAccessor="start"
  endAccessor="end"
  defaultView="year"
  onCreateOrEdit={onCreateOrEdit}
  views={{
    year: YearView
  }}
  components={{
    toolbar: Toolbar
  }}
/>
```

The thing to know is that not all Calendar props are passed down to all of it's internal components. Your custom `View` component can pass the prop to components it renders, but the `Calendar` does not. They are passed down to the current `View` on render, but you would never have access to that prop in the `Toolbar`. You can see this, by reading the source code of the `render()` method of the [Calendar](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/src/Calendar.js) component.

Answer (score 0):

add the title method to YearView component:

```
function YearView(...) { return (...) }

YearView.title = () => ('title text')
```